# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: window.testSpread.getActiveSheet is not a function

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, spreadjs

I'm trying to access the `spreadjs` canvas for one of my automation project with selenium java

This is code snippet I'm using for the same

URL: https://developer.mescius.com/spreadjs/demos/features/table-sheet/overview/purejs

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.testSpread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.findControl(document.querySelector(\"[gcuielement=\'gcWorksheetCanvas\']\"))");
Object value = js.executeScript("return window.testSpread.getActiveSheet().getValue(0,0,);");
```

Getting the below error while running the code

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: window.testSpread.getActiveSheet is not a function
```

Comment: `.getValue(0,0,)` - There is an extra comma(`,`).

Comment: removed but still not working

Answer (score 0):

can you console.log the value of window.testSpread?
also, note that findControl is a static function, no "new"
spread = GC.Spread.Sheets.findControl(host);

Comment: It showing undefined even after removing the new keyword